# Texture colors replaced by purple tones

Tags: opengl, nim-lang

I try to display a texture on a quad but the colors was replaced by some purple.
    [image]

The code is inspired from "learnopengl" website but I didn't find what I failed.
Here the shaders.

```
vertSrc:cstring = """
    #version 330 core

    layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
    layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

    out vec2 texCoord;
    uniform mat4 projection;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
        texCoord = aTexCoord;
    }
    """
fragSrc:cstring = """
    #version 330 core

    out vec4 FragColor;
    in vec2 texCoord;

    uniform sampler2D matTexture;

    void main()
    {
        FragColor = texture(matTexture, texCoord);
    }

    """
```

The opengl code for the texture.

```
glGenTextures(1, addr textureID)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, addr imageData[0])
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

The image loading thanks to the stb_image library.

```
var 
textureID:OGLuint
texWidth:OGLint
texHeight:OGLint
channelCount:OGLint
imageData = stbi_load("Test/2d-rendering-test./stack.png", addr texWidth, addr texHeight, addr channelCount, 0)
```

And the opengl code in the main loop.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID)
```

If you are curious here a complete nim file who displays the issue.
https://bitbucket.org/Neotry/2d-rendering-test./src/master/WIPtest.nim

Comment: Why are you grabbing `channelCount` from `stbi_load()` and then ignoring that information in your `glTexImage2D()` call in favor of assuming `imageData` is always `GL_RGB`?  Are you sure `imageData` isn't `GL_BGR`?

Comment: @genpfault The stbi_load function require an adress to an integer. The channelCount value is 3. I tried GL_BGR but that leads to other fancy colors.

Comment: @Ploumploum The PNG file has 4 channels. Try to read 4 channels explicitly: `stbi_load("...", addr texWidth, addr texHeight, addr channelCount, 4)`. The internal format of the texture finally is `GL_RGBA`, and the format may be `GL_RGBA` or `GL_BGRA`

Comment: @Rabbid76 The "internal format" argument has no effect on this image, but the "format" solved the issue (alongside the last stbi_load argument). You can turn your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Portable Network Graphics (PNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) file may contain 32-bit RGBA colors.

Force the `stbi_load` to generate an image with 4 color channels, by explicitly pass 4 to the last parameter:

```
imageData = stbi_load("Test/2d-rendering-test./stack.png",
                      addr texWidth, addr texHeight, addr channelCount, 4)
```

See [stb_image.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h):

> ```
> Basic usage (see HDR discussion below for HDR usage):
>       int x,y,n;
>       unsigned char *data = stbi_load(filename, &x, &y, &n, 0);
>       // ... process data if not NULL ...
>       // ... x = width, y = height, n = # 8-bit components per pixel ...
> ```
>
> **`// ... replace '0' with '1'..'4' to force that many components per pixel`**
>
> ```
>       // ... but 'n' will always be the number that it would have been if you said 0
>       stbi_image_free(data)
> ```

Finally the format parameter of `glTexImage2D` has to be `GL_RGBA` or `GL_BGRA`. For the internal format can be kept `GL_RGB`:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, addr imageData[0])
```